# Как анимировать прогрессбар?

Tags: css, css-animation

Есть компонент прогрессБара. Данные для прогресса берутся с базы данных. Использования `JS` - не желательно.

Задача стоит в том, чтобы сделать анимацию `width` от 0 до текущего значения(прописан в атрибуте style).

Генерация `keyframes` для каждого прогресса - не очень подходит. Думал также использовать класс с нулевыми значениями, а когда страница загрузила убирать его и сделать анимацию с использованием `transition`. Сейчас остановился на идеи с `max-width`. Анимация width: 0->100%, все работает, кроме скорости анимации. Точнее она у них одинаковая.

Собственно вопрос: Есть ли способ, сделать лучше? Всем спасибо!

```css
.progress-bar{
  width: 500px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #aaa;
  margin: 10px 0; 
}

.progress-bar .progress{
  background: #f00;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: width100 2s backwards;
}

@keyframes width100{
  0% {
    width: 0
  }
  100%{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
   <div class='progress-bar'>
       <div class='progress' style='max-width: 75%'></div>
    </div>
    
     <div class='progress-bar'>
       <div class='progress' style='max-width: 50%'></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class='progress-bar'>
       <div class='progress' style='max-width: 20%'></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте css переменные и можете не менять анимации (вы можете менять css переменные для элементов даже через js)
Я также решил анимировать не `width`, а `transform`, который предназначен для анимаций

```css
.progress-bar {
  width: 500px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #aaa;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.progress-bar .progress {
  --time: 1s; /** Значение по умолчанию для времени анимации **/
  background: #f00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  animation: scale var(--time) forwards;
}

@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='progress-bar'>
  <div class='progress' style='max-width: 75%; --time: 10s'></div>
</div>

<div class='progress-bar'>
  <div class='progress' style='max-width: 50%; --time: 2s'></div>
</div>

<div class='progress-bar'>
  <div class='progress' style='max-width: 20%; --time: 1s'></div>
</div>
```

С цветом:
CSS переменные делают магию, они умеют наследоваться по правилам СSS

```css
.progress-bar {
  width: 500px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #aaa;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.progress-bar .progress {
  --time: 1s; /** Значение по умолчанию для времени анимации **/
  background-color: #f00;
  --colorBar: #f00; /** Значение по умолчанию для конечного цвета **/
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  animation: scale var(--time) forwards;
}

@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: var(--colorBar);
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='progress-bar'>
  <div class='progress' style='max-width: 75%; --time: 3s; --colorBar: black;'></div>
</div>

<div class='progress-bar'>
  <div class='progress' style='max-width: 50%; --time: 2s; --colorBar: yellow;'></div>
</div>

<div class='progress-bar'>
  <div class='progress' style='max-width: 20%; --time: 1s;'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не плохой вариант. А можно ли передать переменную с style в анимацию keyframes ( локально), чтобы для каждого элемента свое значение?

Comment: @Node_pro так и работает, сейчас поставлю для первого прогрeсс-бара 10 секунд

Comment: Уточню вопрос, если не задержку ставить, а передавать max-width?

Comment: @Node_pro вы хотите что-то типа: 100% анимировать за 1 секунду, 50% за 0.5, 25% За 0.25?

Comment: @Node_pro я не понимаю какая задержка, вроде тут время анимации

Comment: Можно ли переменную с атрибута style передать каким-то образом в keyframes. Например для каждого прогресс бара, я хочу сделать плавную смену цвета. Можно ли как-то это сделать используя 1 keyframes, или придется дублировать?

Comment: вроде вы хотели спросить, можно ли значение css переменной назначить max-width. Да, можно. Можно любому свойству задать значение css переменной

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116939/discussion-between---and-node-pro).

Answer (score 0):

Надо задать разную скорость анимации же.

Вот (max-width у всех сделал одинаковым для наглядности):

```css
.progress-bar {
  width: 500px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #aaa;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.progress-bar .progress {
  background: #f00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.progress-bar .progress.fast   {animation: width100 1s backwards;}
.progress-bar .progress.medium {animation: width100 4s backwards;}
.progress-bar .progress.slow   {animation: width100 10s backwards;}

@keyframes width100 {
  0% {
    width: 0
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='progress-bar'>
  <div class='progress fast' style='max-width: 75%'></div>
</div>

<div class='progress-bar'>
  <div class='progress medium' style='max-width: 75%'></div>
</div>

<div class='progress-bar'>
  <div class='progress slow' style='max-width: 75%'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно конечно if- прогнать и добавить класс (slow|medium|fast), но надеялся, что есть способ, который анимацию запускает от 0 до текущих. Иногда такой эффект можно увидеть, когда css файл подгружается с задержкой + transition